# Using Knockout.js with third party control libraries

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm researching Knockout.js and I'm very impressed with its capabilities.  The one thing that has me stuck so far is finding a JavaScript control library that will work with it.  The examples on the Knockout website seem to work only with simple HTML controls.

I would like to use much more feature rich controls like those in jQuery UI, kendo, Wijmo, or Telerik.  I found KOGrid (https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Getting-Started) while researching this.  While I certainly applaud the developer on his efforts, I'm looking for something that is quite feature rich and more mature.

Can anyone suggest any third party control libraries (commercial or otherwise) that work well with Knockout.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make them all work but you will have to use custom bindings, there are already some bindings for jqueryUI, and for Kendo, here is the link for kendo UI bindings http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-bindings-for-kendo-ui.html

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information!  I'm going to wait one more day, in case anyone else wants to chime in with experience with other 3rd party libraries.